# How to calculate excel multiple columns via Macro/VBA if last column first cell is blank?

Tags: excel, vba

My Excel looks likes (total columns 6) but macro count 5. {last column is mixed with no. and blank cells}

```
A B C D E 
F G H I J K
L M N O P
Q R S T U V
W X Y Z
```

I have used range option but it's only working for single sheet for multiple sheets it's not working.

```
colCount = Sheet1.Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Column
```

This gives me count is 6. 
Please let me know for the multiple sheets.

Comment: Check out `Sheet1.UsedRange.Columns.Count`. If this is not what you need then clarify your question ([edit]). See [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long, LastColumn As Long, i As Long, MaxColumn As Long

    MaxColumn = 0

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To LastRow

            LastColumn = .Cells(i, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

            If LastColumn > MaxColumn Then
                MaxColumn = LastColumn
            End If

        Next i

        Debug.Print MaxColumn

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data starts at cell A1, this will work:

```
colCount = 0
For Each cel In sheet1.Range(sheet1.Cells(1, 1), sheet1.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown))
    c = sheet1.Cells(cel.Row, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
    If c > colCount Then colCount = c
Next cel
```

If you have blanks in your cells, **this won't work**, like Pᴇʜ noted in the comments. In this case, use the code below:

```
colCount = 0
For Each cel In sheet1.Range(sheet1.Cells(1, 1), sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    c = sheet1.Cells(cel.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    If c > colCount Then colCount = c
Next cel
```

Comment: Note that this will not work on data like `| A | B | (blank)  | D | E |` that has blank cells where it only counts 2

Comment: You're right @Pᴇʜ, I edit my answer to fit that scenario.